# Not able to extend wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser

Tags: media-library

New to WP development here so please bear with me if I'm missing something simple...
I am writing a plugin for the Media upload library which needs to get the selected media items in Grid View (for drag & drop). I know that the items in the media grid are dynamically generated, so I'm trying to extend the AttachmentsBrowser, and get those elements there during `initialize()`. However, `initialize()` is never called.

```
!function(e) {
  
  var i = {
    init: function() {
      console.log("This is called");

      wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser = wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser.extend({
        initialize: function () { 
          console.log("This is NOT called.");
        },
      });
    }
  }
  
e(document).ready(function() {
    i.init()
})
}(jQuery);
```

I've checked that wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser exists. But somehow `initialize()` doesn't appear to get called. Is there something else that I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason this happened is because when I registered/enqueued the script, I had `in_footer = true`. Setting this to the default of `false` solved the problem.